# Error in Conditional Hyper link Command

Tags: excel-2007

I am trying to execute the conditional hyper link command. Command is as follows:

```
=IF(B4="ADD NEW CATTLE",HYPERLINK("Format-1","CLICK HERE"),"")
```

When B4 cell contains the string "ADD NEW CATTLE" and the user clicks on the cell B5 another worksheet file named as "Format-1" of the same excel file should open but whenever I click on B5 cell I get an error message saying: "Cannot open the specified file". Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your workbook name is `testbook`, please try:

```
=IF(B4="ADD NEW CATTLE",HYPERLINK("[testbook.xlsx]'Format-1'!A1","CLICK HERE"),"")
```

or adjust the A1 reference to suit.